# Insert zero before a numeric datatype in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was trying insert a value in a column in SQL Server which is of type `numeric(18, 0)`.

I am unable to insert a zero at the beginning. For example adding `022223` gets inserted as `22223`...

I think changing the column type to `varchar` will work but I don't want to alter table structure.

Any way to do this without changing the table structure..Please help

Comment: what is the column data type?

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili its numeric(18, 0)

Comment: You could also add the zero when selecting from the database, which should lead to the same effect.

Comment: A numeric value is **numeric** - it doesn't have leading zeroes other formatting applied to it. If you need to show it with leading zeroes - do so in your reporting tool or your UI frontend - that's not the job of SQL Server.

Comment: @Eggi all values dont have leading zeros.hence that could not be done

Comment: If not all values have leading zeros then there should be at least a rule how to add them (length?). Answer below is exactly what I meant.

Comment: you can store value as floating point .and when reading multiply it to a constant.

Comment: If you are trying to handle strings of digits which sometimes start with one or more zeroes then you are correct, the data type should be one of the character string types like `VARCHAR`.  If the data is always numeric and fixed width, e.g. a five digit ZIP code, then it can be a numeric data type and formatted with leading zeroes for display.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point to have this IN a database. You will, afterall, select the data, won't you? So while selecting do something like [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/10/sql-server-pad-ride-side-of-number-with-0-fixed-width-number-display/). I looked in google for "mssql numeeric leading zeros". All of the solutions are like in the link I have mentioned :) Or obviously, use varchar if you, for some reason, must have data like that in a table :)

Comment: actually all variables dont have a zero before them so i cant append values before them.May be i should change the database column time to varchar

Comment: @karthi: do **NOT** change the datatype just for display purposes! If the value you're storing is indeed a number, you should use a numeric datatype! The data being stored shouldn't be altered just for some display "cosmetic" - you can always change the display on reports or the UI of your application. Do **NOT** pick a "wrong" datatype just to handle some display requirement! You'll regret it - rather sooner than later.....

Answer (score 1):

you can apply a transformation when reading and inserting the value like this:

when inserting value :

```
string s = "00056";
 double val = double.Parse("0." + s);
```

and when querying value use:

```
double value = 0.00056; // stored value in your db field
 s = val.ToString().Remove(0,2);
```

i think it will work in any case - whether you have leading zero in your value or not.

Answer (score 0):

Well I dont think it's possible, since its being stored as a 32 bit so simply add leading zeros when printing it ...
There are multiple approaches.
http://sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/padleadingzeros/